# Dealing with SIGSEGV . C

Tags: c

Suppose we are given a task to write a function that sums 2 numbers. I wrote the following code:

```
int main(int ac, char **av) {
   int x = atoi(av[1]);
   int y = atoi(av[2]);
   if (x > 0 & y > 0)
       {
       sum(x, y)
       }
   else 
       {
       return 0;
       }
   return 0;
}
```

But when I am given an input:

```
./a.out 2
```

I catch SIGSEVG. Please explain how do I deal with that problem.

Comment: What were you expecting? Per the standard, given your single input argument, av[2] is NULL, and you're asking `atoi` to dereference it. Your program has only two args in av, at av[0] (the program name), and av[1] (2). What happens when you comply with the expectations of your program and actually give it two actual command-line arguments (./a.out 2 2 , for example)? Better still, why are you blatantly using av[1] and av[2] without verifying beforehand there is something there (i.e. if (ac > 2)) ?

Comment: Got it. At the beginning of the assignment operation I placed if else to check whether argv[1] and argv[2] is NULL. That works. Is it a correct way do to this? Or there is a better way ?

Comment: That's not the correct way to do it. Should check `argc` first to determine which of the `av` entries are valid before accessing any of the `av` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're calling your program, `argv[2]` is `NULL`.  The `atoi` function, therefore, is dereferencing an invalid pointer, hence the segfault.

You should always check the value of `argc` before using any of the command-line arguments.